set one slice state to another in redux toolkit. (react native)
i have two slices in my redux toolkit store:
RootMissions:
type RootMissionStoreType = {
  key: string;
  title: string;
  missions: Record<string, MissionStoreType>;
};

type RootMissionsSliceState = {
  rootMissions: Record<string, RootMissionStoreType>;
};

const initialState: RootMissionsSliceState = {
  rootMissions: {},
};

export const RootMissionsSlice = createSlice({
  name: SLICES_NAMES.rootMissions,
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    // some actions...
  },
});

and Missions:
type MissionsSliceState = {
  missions: Record<string, MissionStoreType>;
  focusedMission: string | null;
};

const initialState: MissionsSliceState = {
  missions: {},
  focusedMission: null,
};

export const MissionsSlice = createSlice({
  name: SLICES_NAMES.missions,
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    // some actions...
  },
});

as you can see, the type of my missionsSlice.mission is the same as the values in rootMissionsSlice.rootMissions.
i want to be able, by dispatching action or something else, to take all the data from the missionsSlice.missions and set it inside rootMissionsSlice.rootMissions[id] (by given id, like in the action payload..)
this is what i have done yet:
in one of my components i have this code:
  const allMissions = useAppSelector(MissionsSelector);
  //...
    const handleBackPress = () => {
    dispatch(
      setRootMissionMissions({ key: route.params.key, missions: allMissions })
    );
  };

the problem in this solution, that i need to render my component for every change in my missions..
I'm looking for a better approach for it, that will not cause new renders at all..
Thanks!

Sorry, it's unclear why you have and want duplicate state in the store. Can you [edit] to clarify if I've misunderstood, and to provide more and better/clearer details what the issue or problem is? When do you want the missions state to be copied to the root missions state? The button seems to be a valid way to do this.

its like a "stash" state, that you edit the missions as you want, and than, when you press on the button, it should copy all the data you have change and set it to the rootMissions slice. as i said, the bottom working but cause a lot of rendering i want to avoid.. Thanks G-d a have manage to solve it, i will add the answer to that question soon..

i have create a global action like so:
const setMissionToRootMission =
  (key: string) => (dispatch: AppDispatch, getState: () => RootState) => {
    const state = getState();
    dispatch(
      setRootMissionMissions({ key, missions: state.missions.missions })
    );
  };

and get call it in the handle function:
const handleBackPress = () => {
  dispatch(setMissionToRootMission(route.params.key));
};

